# javascript checkbox not reacting when clicking, always have to press submit

Tags: php, javascript, forms, checkbox

For some reason I can't get to work a script I have been trying out for a few days.

I have some checkboxes that show different colors. When the user clicks on one color I want the script to reload one of the DIVs of my website.

Everything works fine with the `<form>` tags and an `<input type="submit">`, basically with a button. But it never works by just checking a checkbox, I always have to click on submit.

Any help with the code would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

javascript:

```
<script>
    $('.colors').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() { 
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            var id = $("#regularCheckbox").find(':checked').val();
            $('#itemMain').load('index.php?color='+id);
        }
    }).find('input:checkbox').change();
</script>
```

form:

```
<?php
$colors = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT color_base1 FROM item_descr ORDER BY color_base1");
while ($colorBoxes = mysql_fetch_array($colors))
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-1-1' class='regularCheckbox' name='color' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   ".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."</font><br />";
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() { ... });`?

Comment: Is there only one checkbox, or is it a radio box? Could you please show us the DOM/HTML?

Comment: @Matt - Yes, not working either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#regularCheckbox").find(':checked')
```

seems to be wrong based on your PHP echo. `regularCheckbox` is a class, not an id, so you will want to select `$(".regularCheckbox:checked')`. Btw, you should not output the same id repeatedly in a loop, ids need to be unique.

Also, you might just want to use jQuery's [`serialize()` method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on your form.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the # for . but still clicking on a box doesnt reload the DIV... any clue of what can be going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "*doesnt reload the DIV*"? Is the `change` hanlder not called? Is the Ajax not executed? Is the Ajax response invalid, and only the DOM not updated?

Comment: $('#itemMain').load('index.php?color='+id);
This part doesn't happen when I check/click the box

Comment: And why do you think it would not happen? Does it break and show an exception in your error console or what?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.php:26
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.php:61
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.php:73

Comment: ...but the line before works? Um, if jQuery is not defined, include the script!